# Create a PDF and print it to default printer Electron

Tags: javascript, printing, electron, local

i'm building an electron app that needs to create a pdf file and print it to a local printer as autonomously as possible. Just like FPDF works with php and python, but i need an alternative for JS. otherwise is it possible to bundle php on an electron app? how would a bundle a server on it? just want to build an standalone app that doesnt require the computer to have xampp or something alike installed for it to work.
i already have the UI made on html and css, also a couple functions on JS that work flawlessly, my main issue is creating the pdf and printing it.
i would like to avoid any escpos library since drivers and zadig are a nightmare for me.

Comment: I've had success using [jsPDF](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html) to generate PDFs. No experience printing from Electron.

Comment: jsPDF seems easier to save the pdf to local, appreciate it. just need a way to open that file with js and send it to the printer